# 5th net of private class B when SM is 16?

Tags: networking, subnet

I need to calculate a network with VLSM. It says I should start with the 5th net of private class B when subnet mask is 16. What is this 5th net?

The network looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34140308/uploads/IMG_20150108_074523.jpg

Comment: Well, do you know what is the first class B private network?

Comment: 172.16.0.0 afaik, why?

Comment: Yes, so the second is 172.17.0.0, 172.18.0.0 third etc... Also your question is offtopic: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Is this true even when SM is 16? Usually the SM of a class B network is 12, not 16.

Comment: Class B network mask is always 255.255.0.0.

Comment: no? usually it's 12 -> 255.240.0.0

Comment: @Exceen, Class B is /16. (Class A: /8, Class B: /16 and Class C: /24)

Comment: that's for public network classes, I'm talking about private classes

Comment: @Exceen, you are correct. I was mixing public/private. So for a private class B address using a /16 mask `172.20.0.0/16` is the fifth subnet (if I calculated correctly).

Comment: But why am I still allowed to modify those bits? Doesn't the subnet mask forbid this? I know that i's fine when SM is 12, I don't get the point why it would still be correct with SM 16

Comment: @Exceen, because 172.16.0.0/12 is the entire range you can use. You are just subnetting in that range.

Comment: But I'm not talking about 172.160.0.0/12, I'm talking about 172.16.0.0/16 which has the range 172.16.0.0-172.16.255.255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceen, it's easier if I write it as an answer.

**The private class B network is 172.16.0.0/12**.

You need to use subnet mask `/16`, so every private class B network is `0.0.255.255` large or a little more than `65k hosts per subnet`.

- 1st subnet: 172.16.0.0/16
- 2nd subnet: 172.17.0.0/16
- 3rd subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
- 4th subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
- 5th subnet: 172.20.0.0/16.

You'll need to use `172.20.0.0/16` for your network diagram. From the diagram we can tell you need `8 subnets`. So you can either split the `172.20.0.0/16` range into `172.20.0.0/24 - 172.20.8.0/24` or use VLSM to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally got it